# Angular 4 Router: show view without redirect

Tags: angular, angular-router

In AngularJs with UI-Router, I could do the following to have any unauthorized or non-existing state to be shown a particular view without need of redirecting so the user could know what route/url was the unsuccessful one:

```
.state('notauthorized', {
    templateUrl: 'notauthorized.html'
})
.state('notfound', {
    templateUrl: 'notfound.html'
});
```

Now I'm working on Angular 4 with the built-in RouteModule. Is there any way to accomplish the same without redirecting the user to a completely different route??

Comment: Perhaps you could use a resolver or guard with a promise that resolves when the user has interacted with a modal? So this resolver/guard will check if the user has the needed rights, if it does not, it will show a modal. When the additional info has been filled in the user can click cancel or ok to either be allowed or denied access to the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if that's possible but you could always redirect to the 'not found' view, but tell the router to not change the URL so it appears to the user that they are still on the same page / URL.

use the skipLocationChange option from here https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

in the component:

```
 router.navigateByUrl("/pathToYourNotFoundView", { skipLocationChange: true });
```

or if it was a link in the template -

```
<a [routerLink]="..." skipLocationChange>click me</a>
```

Comment: That's a great idea! Definitely something to try.

Comment: Looks very promising. I think it might work the right way if I combine this with a route Guard to check first if the route exists and/or if it's authorized. I will try it tomorrow and let you know. Thanks!!

Comment: Took a while, but eventually tried it and work perfectly! Just what I was looking for.
And by setting the last route on the router configuration to match `path: '**'`, it doesn't redirect to another URL, it just remains on the url just entered and loads the view for the component specified without a redirection.

Answer (score 0):

It's been too long since I've used UI-Router that I don't remember how it works, so this may not be what you are describing.

But with Angular, every template has a component. So you'd need a component for your "notauthorized" and your "notfound" templates. Or you could do one component with one template that displayed text defining either "not authorized" or "not found".

For example, my page not found component looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: `
    <h1>This is not the page you were looking for!</h1>
    `
})
export class PageNotFoundComponent { }
```

You could instead make this more generalized like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    template: `
    <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    `
})
export class MessageComponent {
    message: string;

}
```

Would this support your scenario?

To retain the user's "current" route before re-routing, you could build a service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    currentUrl: string;

}
```

Then, when something goes wrong somewhere, you would have code like this:

```
    this.messageService.currentUrl = url;
    this.router.navigate(['/pageNotFound']);
```

You could then retrieve the currentUrl to display it or whatever.

Comment: This is the first thing that came to my mind when I started working on this in the new Angular but as far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong), this would need a redirect to another route, right? Which would kill my intention of showing the user "ok, this is the url you wanted to access, but you're either unauthorized or it doesn't exist".

Comment: I don't get exactly what you want to achieve, but maybe what you need is a **Guard** see: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/.

Comment: @CesarD You could still capture their route before rerouting. I do this when I route to a login page. If the user routes to route A, I route first to a login page. And since I saved that they were trying to get to route A, I can take them to A after the login. You could do something similar to retain their route